# Modifying a POST request to denote quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, opencart

I am currently working on allowing the administrator to choose the quantity to remove in the `Orders -> Product` page in the administrative backend, as shown here:

[image]

The default behavior right now is that if you want to remove the product, the entire quantity is remove (with no way to select how many to remove).

Looking at the POST requests sent in the AJAX (when you press the red "remove" button) in `/admin/view/template/sale/order_form.tpl`, I noticed that the following code below, denoted as `order_total` is in charge of product removal (apologies for the incredibly long line of code - that's just how OpenCart's code convention is.. One big line).

```
for (i in json['order_total']) {
    total = json['order_total'][i];

    html += '<tr id="total-row' + total_row + '">';
    html += '  <td class="right" colspan="4"><input type="hidden" name="order_total[' + total_row + '][order_total_id]" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[' + total_row + '][code]" value="' + total['code'] + '" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[' + total_row + '][title]" value="' + total['title'] + '" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[' + total_row + '][text]" value="' + total['text'] + '" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[' + total_row + '][value]" value="' + total['value'] + '" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[' + total_row + '][sort_order]" value="' + total['sort_order'] + '" />' + total['title'] + ':</td>';
    html += '  <td class="right">' + total['value'] + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    console.log(html + "\n");

    total_row++;
}

$('#total').html(html);
```

As I saw within this hidden form request string, there is no way to define a key such as "quantity." In fact, I actually don't really have an idea on how it even removes an item, let alone the ability to modify the quantity. An example request string look like this:

```
<tr id="total-row0">  <td class="right" colspan="4"><input type="hidden" name="order_total[0][order_total_id]" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[0][code]" value="sub_total" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[0][title]" value="Sub-Total" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[0][text]" value="$0.00" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[0][value]" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[0][sort_order]" value="1" />Sub-Total:</td>  <td class="right">0</td></tr><tr id="total-row1">  <td class="right" colspan="4"><input type="hidden" name="order_total[1][order_total_id]" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[1][code]" value="total" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[1][title]" value="Total" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[1][text]" value="$0.00" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[1][value]" value="0" /><input type="hidden" name="order_total[1][sort_order]" value="9" />Total:</td>  <td class="right">0</td></tr>
```

From my basic understanding, it seems to update the entire order total. Apologies for my ignorance.. I am totally new to JS/jQuery.

Comment: Try inspecting the element in the debugger and getting the element associated with the quantity in that form. Once you have the `name` of the element, you can easily pass it along in that `POST` request and also modify it provided that field is already not present in that huge string. We can't pin point which element corresponds to which name properly unless there is a fiddle or some more sample html may be to show the structure of that form.

Comment: @VivekPradhan As far as I could tell, if you remove a product, it does not have an associated quantity key (I've looked *everywhere*). Adding a product (to that list) does, however, but calls another script. It's really weird architecture back there. The example request string is what gets POSTed, which updates the total.

Comment: Made my day: *apologies for the incredibly long line of code - that's just how OpenCart's code convention is.. One big line* ROFL. So true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is what I found out when I opened the `order_form.tpl` - the deletion is done simply by removing a row from table (yes, in HTML words a `<tr>` is removed from `<tbody>`) and saving the order (updating). And because the whole table containing products is also a form (literaly, i.e. `<form>`) full of hidden inputs it should be possible to change the quantity the very same way as is done on frontend in `checkout/cart`.

If I were you I'd add a spinner input instead of textual representation for quantity, because this column (quantity) goes like this:

```
<td class="right"><?php echo $order_product['quantity']; ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="order_product[<?php echo $product_row; ?>][quantity]" value="<?php echo $order_product['quantity']; ?>" />
</td>
```

If you could change it for something like this:

```
<td class="right">
  <input type="text" name="order_product[<?php echo $product_row; ?>][quantity]" value="<?php echo $order_product['quantity']; ?>" />
</td>
```

(i.e. remove textual representation and change input hidden to input text) while optionally making the input as +/- (spinner) field, this could solve your problem.

Of course, in the end, you'd need to either click on *Save* or add also another small button next to the quantity input, something like

```
<td class="right">
  <input type="text" name="order_product[<?php echo $product_row; ?>][quantity]" value="<?php echo $order_product['quantity']; ?>" />
  <input type="image" src="view/image/update.png" alt="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" onclick="$('#button-update').trigger('click');" />
</td>
```

This could work for you ;-)

Comment: Hey @shadyyx - I actually did try changing it to `text` instead of `hidden`, and while it would update the quantity, it would not change the total (meaning it doesn't update anything in the back-end). Am I right or wrong in this assessment?

Comment: So after changing the quantity and clicking on SAVE the totals are not counted properly? And the quantity remains as before or is it that new updated one? Maybe the update method does not count with the quantity change (only with products being added or removed) so then you'd need to check the controller and update method.

Comment: Quantity changes on-save, but total does not change =).

Comment: OK, and did you take a look on why and tried to solve it or are you waiting that somebody will solve everything for you? If you want to learn programming and be good the best option is to try everything by yourself. To search for mistakes, debug, read documentations, understand the code. If you will be waiting for others' solutions, you'd be *mentally stuck*...

Comment: I'm working on a refund system on the admin page right now, so I am unable to work on this problem at the moment. I will need to get back to it - but thank you for your pointers. I will definitely be using them.